# Postgres giving fatal error while running my application through JBOSS

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jboss, connection-pool

I am running my application through *JBoss* with postgresql database but giving me max connection error but through *PGAdmin* I am able to connect database

> 17:14:44,917 ERROR [STDERR] [WARNING]
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourceP ool$AcquireTask@52900718 --
>   Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acqui res. While trying
>   to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more th an the
>   maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (2). Last acquisition
>   atte mpt exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL:
>   remaining connection sl ots are reserved for non-replication superuser
>   connections
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(Conn

Comment: Somewhere you are not closing connections properly.

Comment: it is giving me this error immediately after starting JBoss . I checked the pid of postgre so it showing more than 500 connection how can i kill pid from pgadmin. I am not able to use command prompt becuase I am setting my application on aws

Comment: so you have mis-configured your connection pool to open too many connections on startup.

Comment: You can cancel sessions using `pg_terminate_backend`. You seem to have a connection leak somewhere in your code.

Comment: how can i use pg_terminate_backend please tell me exact procedure i am new for it

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file:

```
/etc/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

And increase number off connections like:

```
max_connections = 100
```